# Flask - Model not resetting after submit?

Tags: python-3.x, class, flask

I have a model for:

```
class DnaString:
    complement_dict = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}
    contents = {'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, dnastring):
        for nucleotide in dnastring:
            cls.contents[nucleotide] += 1


    def __init__(self, dnastring):
        self.dnastring = dnastring
        self.update(dnastring)
```

And a View:

```
@protein.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('get_protein.html')
    else:
        dnastring = DnaString(request.form['dnastring'])
        return render_template('dna_analysis.html',
                               dnacontents=dnastring.contents)
```

When I enter a dna string for the first time it works, however if I refresh the page and enter another dna string, it looks like it doesn't create a new instance of DnaString and instead add to the same instance. So, if I enter a dna string once hit refresh and enter the same string, the contents will print out double.

Is there a way to create a new instance of DnaString each time I run the page?

I guess I could make contents a class method instead? But from my understanding, the reason for objects is that they are each independent? For example, `Human` can be a class but if I assign it to a variable `john = Human()` then `john` is it's own instance the `Human` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@classmethod` is not what you want here. This will mutate a class variable (as opposed to an instance variable). A simpler version of this can be seen here:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     l = []
...     @classmethod
...     def add(cls, x):
...         cls.l.append(x)
...
>>> Foo.l
[]
>>> Foo.add(2)
>>> Foo.l
[2]
>>> Foo.add(2)
>>> Foo.l
[2, 2]
```

You should instantiate a new object with each request if it can't be found in your persistence layer.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.l = []
...     def add(self, x):
...         self.l.append(x)
...
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo1.add(2)
>>> foo1.l
[2]
>>> foo1.add(2)
>>> foo1.l
[2, 2]
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> foo2.add(2)
>>> foo2.l
[2]
```